# Copy content of a subsystem to another subsystem in the same model

Tags: matlab, simulink

I am searching for a way to copy the content of one Subsystem to another existing Subsystem in the same model via code. Is there a best practise?

Thank you

Comment: This is a pretty broad question, and "best practise" questions tend to attract opinionated answers... That said, if it's exact functionality you're copying, you could use [custom libraries and linked blocks](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/about-block-libraries.html).

Comment: Hi and thanks for your answer. In my case i allways have to copy different contens, so working with libraries will not help. I just want so be able to copy the content of any subsystem to another subsystem via skript.

Comment: Then this isn't even really a best practise question, it's a "Please give me code to programmatically do this thing", which is also hard to answer. Give a simple example model, and code you've tried and why it doesn't work, ...

Answer (score 3):

This is not so difficult but little tricky.
You can copy the contents of your subsystem to a new block diagram first (temporary destination) using *Simulink.SubSystem.copyContentsToBlockDiagram*. You should also use
*save_system* command.

Then from this temporary destination file you can copy the contents to the desired subsystem in final destination block diagram using *Simulink.BlockDiagram.copyContentsToSubsystem*. Then you can use commands like save_system and close_system. This retains whatever SIL/PIL 'test harnesses' you have created.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [add_block](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/add_block.html)

If your Model is called `ModelSource` and the subsystem you want to copy is called `Subsystem1` and you are creating a copy to the same model, you can copy that subsystem using the command

```
add_block('ModelSource/Subsystem1','ModelSource/Subsystem1','MakeNameUnique','on')
```

The "MakeNameUnique" will ensure that your new block has a unique name.

Note that the new block will have the same coordinates as the old block.
You can move the block down by doing

```
coords = get_param(gcb,'Position');
coords(2) = coords(2) + 50;
coords(4) = coords(4) + 50;
set_param(gcb,'Position',coords);
```

Which will move the block 50 pixels down from the location of the source block.

Comment: Also be aware of functionality like [simulink.blockdiagram.copycontentstosubsystem](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/simulink.blockdiagram.copycontentstosubsystem.html) and [simulink.subsystem.copycontentstoblockdiagram](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/simulink.subsystem.copycontentstoblockdiagram.html), which are useful in other, but similar, situations.